# Error on onclick

Tags: android, android-intent

I want an activity to be leaded when clicking on a button. But my app crashes when this is done.

This is my code where the error is pointed out (`startActivity(intent);`),

```
Button ExerciseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

   ExerciseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Database.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }

    });
```

The xml for the button

```
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:onClick="grammar"
                android:text="@string/button_exercise"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="28dp" />
```

This is the activity which is called,

```
public class Database extends Activity  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


             try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName()
                + "/databases/questions";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("questions"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } 

             catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(Database.this, "Error File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show(); 
    } 
             catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
       Toast.makeText(Database.this, "Error IO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }


        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


        long id = db.addQuestion("Question1", "answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4", "answer");
        //id = db.addQuestion("Question2", "answer2");
        db.close();



       Cursor cursor = db.getAllQuestions();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                DisplayRecord(cursor);

            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        db.close();
    }

        public void CopyDB(InputStream inputstream, OutputStream outputstream)        
                throws IOException {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputstream.read(buffer))>0){
                outputstream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            inputstream.close();
            outputstream.close();
        }

        public void DisplayRecord(Cursor cursor){
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "id:" + cursor.getString(0) + "\n" +
                    "Question:" + cursor.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "Answer1:" + cursor.getString(2) + "\n" +
"Answer2:" + cursor.getString(3) + "\n" +
"Answer3:" + cursor.getString(4) + "\n" +
"Answer4:" + cursor.getString(5) + "\n" +
"Answer:" + cursor.getString(6),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

     }
```

The logcat is below.

```
02-27 10:35:41.061: W/KeyCharacterMap(11469): No keyboard for id 0
02-27 10:35:41.061: W/KeyCharacterMap(11469): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-27 10:35:42.471: D/AndroidRuntime(11469): Shutting down VM
02-27 10:35:42.481: W/dalvikvm(11469): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.grammer/com.example.grammer.Database}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.example.grammer.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:43)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-27 10:35:42.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11469):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-27 10:35:44.961: I/Process(11469): Sending signal. PID: 11469 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post logcat...........

Comment: did you put your Database activity in manifest? Please post your logcat.

Comment: as in log :`Database: have you declared Database activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: @faz declare  your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: After viewing your post i think problem is in your database activity where you copying data base.please check care fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your **manifest** file...

```
<activity android:name=".Database" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the attribute onclick="grammer" in Button widget,but in your MainActivity there's is no grammer method.Probably you should use in this way.

```
public void grammmer(View view)
{ 
    // To do your stuff  
 }
```

or

just the way you did by setting onclicklistener to it like

```
 Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.YourButton);
b1.setonClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
@Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Database.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }

 });
```

and btw, Register your next activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity name=".YourActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the activity added to manifest- which means there's no way for your app to identify your activity.

> All activities must be declared in your manifest file,
>   AndroidManifest.xml, using an `<activity>` element.

Please read more about it, important to know:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.package.name">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Activity1" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem might be out of some following issue...

1) In your `Database.java` you have set `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and your class name is Database so make sure your XML name is correct. Because i think you have `main_activity.java` too so make double sure that you have two differennt XML for both activity. and you are assigning right XML to right Java file.

2) I think you have not set your database name in `manifest` file so as @Anil Bhatiya told, do it that way.

Answer (score -2):

You already set `android:onClick=grammar` in the xml so you don't need to implement onclick listener. Just create a method name as "grammar" and put your intent in that method